# exception handling in the multi thread environment

Tags: c#, .net

I want to know if

try/catch can catch the exceptions thrown by the children threads.

if not, what's the best practice to handling exceptions thrown in the child thread.

Comment: What technology are you using? WinForms, WPF, Console, ASP.net?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can listen to the [`Application.ThreadException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx) and [`AppDomain.UnhandledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) events to catch uncaught exceptions from thread. But the best is to catch and handle exceptions in the threads themselves. This should be a last resort for graceful shutdown / logging.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the .NET framework you're targeting.

In 1.1 and lesser, exceptions thrown by children threads will be forwarded to the main thread only if they run outside a try/catch block.

In 2.0 and later, this behaviour is changed: thread will be terminated and exceptions won't be allowed to proceed any further.

Anyway, you can handle exceptions inside a thread as you would do in a single-threaded application.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228965(v=VS.90).aspx for reference.

Comment: Exceptions thrown by child threads will kill the whole program starting with .NET 2.

Comment: What do you mean by "forwarded to the main thread"? Can you give an example of how this would work and how these exceptions could be caught?

Comment: @cdhowie, what is the best practice to prevent the whole program killing? Catch all the exception in the child and kill it?

Answer (score 1):

No, consider the following code:

```
try
{
   var t = new Thread(()=>
      {
          Thread.Sleep(5000);
          throw new Exception();
      });
   t.Start();
   //t.Join();
}
catch
{
    //you can't deal with exception here
    //even though you uncomment `t.Join`
}
```

Deal with exceptions in the child thread which the exceptions "belongs" to.